# iOS Play Same Video Side by Side like Homido App

Tags: ios, video, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I need a sample app or some theoretical explanation for playing same video side by side as it in [Homido Application](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R-D2b_2K-7c).
Gone through many, but getting for multiple videos playing side by side. Anyone please give your valuable suggestions on this.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible. Please follow these links

1. https://abdulazeem.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/video-manipulation-in-ios-resizingmerging-and-overlapping-videos-in-ios/
2. http://developer.telerik.com/featured/merging-audio-video-native-ios/

you can do this by changing video frames(see 1st url).

Comment: thank you for ur reply, i've already gone through 1st url, but we cant get VR using that i think. In Homido app, VR is there.

Comment: you can use UIImagePickerController or AVCaptureSession to record video. use that url while playing videos.

Comment: thanks for ur time @naresh, i dont think it will work for VR.

Comment: i did already. and its working. try it, don't think it will not work.